# Mercurial keyring and password change on Google Code

Tags: mercurial, google-code, mercurial-keyring, python-keyring

I'm using Mercurial (latest bundled with THG) and have a repo on Google Code. I enabled the `mercurial_keyring` extension and this worked perfectly until I changed the password on my Google account. Now Google Code returns a HTTP 403 error due to the wrong password stored in the keychain, which causes HG to abort the push without asking for the password again.

Is there any way to force the password change on the keyring, or even just to reset it, so that I can re-enter the new password? A tool to manage the stored entries for the python `Win32CryptoKeyring` would also be fine, since I could use that to delete my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question accidentally. Mercurial_keyring tries to detect such cases and re-ask for the password, but for one reason or another this did not work.

I created issue https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial_keyring/issue/45/some-way-to-clear-password-and-maybe to track the problem, anybody wishing to add some information or to follow the work is welcome to track it.

(mercurial_keyring author)

Comment: Thanks Mekk! In the meantime I also found out that the saved credentials can be managed/removed in Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Credential Manager, section Generic Credentials. Maybe this could be mentioned somewhere (I might also just have missed it in the docs).